# Passing parameter from view-model to page and display it

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, command, parameter-passing

I'm stuck with passing parameter from view model to page. On view model page i have list of properties which i increase by button , after button click sum is displyed on same page below that i collected that many of smth, my goal is to send this sum collected on this view model page to new page which i want to be responsible for displaying this sum . I'm stuck with passing parameter, it just don't update the value, it looks like the binding is okey becouse app don't throw exception that object has no reference. I'm begginer in xamarin and for any explanation or just direction which i can follow to achive this I would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

ListViewModel code:

```
    public class PersonListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }

    PersonViewModel selectedPerson;

    double _sumcollected;
    public double SumCollected
    {
        get => _sumcollected;
        set
        {
            if (_sumcollected != value)
            {
                _sumcollected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SumCollected");
            }
        }
    }


    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    public PersonListViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>
        {
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT", Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.1, SavedClicked=0,Weight=1
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.1, SavedClicked=0,Weight=30
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.2, SavedClicked=0,Weight=100
            },
            new PersonViewModel()
            {
                Name="Test", Surname="Test", Description= "TEsT",Background = "bgtest6.jpg", ProgressCounter =0.3, SavedClicked=0,Weight=27
            },
        };
        NavigateCommand = new Command<PersonViewModel>(NavigatationSolved);
        IncreaseProgressCommand = new Command<PersonViewModel>(IncreaseProgress);
        GotoCounterCommand = new Command<PersonListViewModel>(GotoNumbersPage);
        NavigateSumPageCommand = new Command<PersonListViewModel>(NavigateSumPage);

    }

    private void NavigateSumPage(object obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Navigate to sum page ");
        PersonListViewModel personListModel = obj as PersonListViewModel;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new SumPage(personListModel));
    }

    //Passing SumCollected not working
    private void GotoNumbersPage(object numbers)
    {
        PersonListViewModel personList = numbers as PersonListViewModel;

        Navigation.PushAsync(new CounterPage(personList));
        Debug.WriteLine("Next Page ?");
    }


    private void IncreaseProgress(object sender)
    {

        PersonViewModel person = sender as PersonViewModel;

        if(person.ProgressCounter >= 1)
        {
            person.ProgressCounter -= person.ProgressCounter;
            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Message after one progress bar", "GO!");
        }
        else
        {
            person.ProgressCounter += .2;
        }
        //Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new GratulationAlertPage());
        person.SavedClicked += 1;
        Debug.WriteLine("Saved Clicked");
        SumCollected += 1;
        SumCollected += person.Weight;
        Debug.WriteLine("New SumCollected value");
    }
```

}

ListViewModelPage code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CommandDemo.Views.PersonListPage"
         >
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="Numbers"
                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.GotoCounterCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10"
                 Margin="10">
        <ListView x:Name="personList"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  >
            <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"-->
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                      Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference personList},Path=BindingContext.NavigateCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                            <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding ProgressCounter}"/>
                            <Button Text="Add Progress"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference personList},Path=BindingContext.IncreaseProgressCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label Text="{Binding SumCollected}"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Button Text="Numbers"
                Command="{Binding NavigateSumPageCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

SumViewModel code:

```
    public class CounterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private PersonListViewModel _personListView;
        public PersonListViewModel PersonList
        {
            get => _personListView;
            set
            {
                if (_personListView != value)
                {
                    _personListView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PersonList");
                }
            }
        }

        PersonViewModel _personView;
        public PersonViewModel PersonView
        {
            get => _personView;
            set
            {
                if (_personView != value)
                {
                    _personView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PersonView");
                }
            }
        }
        public double SumCollected
        {
            get => PersonList.SumCollected;
            set
            {
                if (PersonList.SumCollected != value)
                {
                    PersonList.SumCollected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SumCollected");
                }
            }
        }
        private double _collected;
        public double Collected
        {
            get => _collected;
            set
            {
                if (_collected != value)
                {
                    _collected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Collected");
                }
            }
        }

        public CounterViewModel()
        {
            PersonList = new PersonListViewModel();

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

Page where i want to display sum collected from list page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CommandDemo.Views.SumPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding PersonList.SumCollected}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Sum page code behind:

```
    public partial class SumPage : ContentPage
{
    public SumPage (PersonListViewModel personListModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new CounterViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must add the CounterPage code behind. You are not passing any object to your viewmodel. Plus, you want to display each person counter? Or just a total number?

Comment: I want to display a total number , just same which is on list page

Comment: Just added code behind of sum page

Comment: In your counterViewModel you need to receive the object that you are passing, or else you get nothing

Comment: It might seem to be stupid question but i was thinking that it's happening by setter and getter on counterViewModel where i created SumCollected object PersonList.SumCollected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive the object that you are passing in your viewmodel.

```
public CounterViewModel(PersonListViewModel personList)
            {
                PersonList =  personList;

            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that !!! :) As you solved my problem , can i ask you one more thing. I guess it some fundamental knowlage i miss ?

Comment: Yes, feel free to ask :) Yes, these are fundamental concepts of OOP